# Usage of _path gives a "No route matches.." error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following a tutorial of Rails and I have a few pages that I am adding some tests for.

I am trying to use help_path instead of :help in my pages_controller_test :

```
test "should get help" do
  get help_path
  assert_response :success
  assert_select "title", "Help | #{@base_title}"
end
```

I added this line in my routes.rb file :

```
 get  '/help',    to: 'pages#help'
```

But I get this error :

> 1) Error:
>   PagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help:
>   ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/help", :controller=>"pages"}
>       test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb:62:in `block in '

I have tried a few solutions but none of them solved my issue.
I've also tried using this line instead :

```
match '/home' => 'main_pages#home', :as => :home
```

But it didn't work either.

My rails version is : 4.2.4
My Ruby version is : ruby 2.1.9p490 (2016-03-30 revision 54437) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Output of $rake routes :

```
 Prefix Verb URI Pattern          Controller#Action
 root GET  /                    pages#home
 help GET  /help(.:format)      pages#help
 courses GET  /courses(.:format)   pages#courses
 programs GET  /programs(.:format)  pages#programs
 schools GET  /schools(.:format)   pages#schools
 dashboard GET  /dashboard(.:format) pages#dashboard
 profile GET  /profile(.:format)   pages#profile
 account GET  /account(.:format)   pages#account
 signout GET  /signout(.:format)   pages#signout
```

EDIT :
I can use help_path .. etc in my html code without any issue, but in the test it gives that error.
Thank you :)

Comment: Do not include the slash in your route definitions (use `'help'` and `'home'` instead). Also, run `rake routes` to view all your routes.

Comment: Can you add your controller and your whole `routes.rb`?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma My application_controller only has a hello function

Comment: @mmichael I tried using 'help' instead but I still got the same error

Comment: Anyways, I've tested the code and it works, adding all the code involved helps to "debug".

Comment: @OuissalBenameur Could you please post the output from `rake routes`?

Comment: `get  '/help',    to: 'pages#help', as: :help` ... does this really not work?

Comment: @mmichael I posted it

Comment: @maxpleaner Yes it doesn't

Comment: What about `get '/help'` in your test?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma it gives the same error, get :help gives no error

Comment: remove the slash from the route name

Comment: @maxpleaner I removed it and still got the same error, it could have something to do with my rails version?

Comment: It'd be great to see a repo.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma  https://github.com/Ouissalb/MOOC-with-Ruby-on-Rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran your tests using the repo, Rails 4.2.4, Minitest 5.10.2 and the only one test that doesn't pass is the one using `get help_path`. I put only the 3 tests in order to shorten the post:

```
PagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help_using_"get_:help" = 0.39 s = .
PagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help_using_"get_help_path" = 0.00 s = E
PagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help_using_"get_'help'" = 0.01 s = .

Finished in 0.405330s, 7.4014 runs/s, 9.8685 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
PagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help_using_"get_help_path":
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/help", :controller=>"pages"}
    test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb:70:in `block in <class:PagesControllerTest>'

3 runs, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

What I did:

```
$ rm -rf Gemfile.lock (because of a json -v 1.8.1 gem error)
$ bundle
$ rake db:migrate
$ rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
$ rake test test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb -v
```

What you can use to make the test work with `help_path` as the route to test specifying the controller and action is to use:

> [`assert_routing`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html#method-i-assert_routing) asserts that the routing of the given path was handled correctly and
>   that the parsed options (given in the expected_options hash) match
>   path. Basically, it asserts that Rails recognizes the route given by
>   expected_options.

Or:

> [`assert_recognizes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html#method-i-assert_recognizes) asserts that path and options match both ways; in other words, it
>   verifies that path generates options and then that options generates
>   path. This essentially combines assert_recognizes and assert_generates
>   into one step.

Like:

```
test "should get help using assert_recognizes and help_path" do
  assert_recognizes({controller: 'pages', action: 'help'}, help_path)
  assert_response :success
end

test "should get help using assert_routing and help_path" do
  assert_routing help_path, controller: 'pages', action: 'help'
  assert_response :success
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for your research. Note assert_routing and assert_recognized in the quotes are reversed.